# About the usage of "make my day"

Tags: phrases

A paragraph goes like:

A cockroach was caught by a man.
About to be put to death, it snapped to the executioner its last words,
"Go ahead and ***kill me***, you coward! You're just jealous, because I can have your wife spooked to scream while you can't."

In this scenario, is it okay if I use "***make my day***" instead of "***kill me***,"
as in Clint Eastwood's famous movie quote?

Thank you.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you using it that way (from the point of view of grammar) but how would executing a man make his day?

Comment: So "make my day" doesn't have the connotation of the phrase "put me out of my misery" in this scenario?

Comment: To me, "make my day" suggests something lasting rather than just a moment of happiness or satisfaction.

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful.

Comment: "Make my day" means "make today an unusually good one for me"

Comment: It would have to be... a suicidal cockroach? 

Answer (score 2):

"**Kill me**" would mean to execute the cockroach, whereas "**make my day**" would mean to make the cockroach very happy.

As in -

> Go ahead and ***make me happy***, you coward! You're just jealous because I can have your wife spooked to scream while you can't."

Which doesn't make sense in your context. How can the cockroach be made to feel happy if he is about to be killed?

Comment: So "make my day" doesn't have the connotation of the phrase "put me out of my misery" in this scenario?

Comment: @Kevin - No, it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Oxford Dictionary

[make someone's day](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/make_someone's_day)

> Make an otherwise ordinary or dull day pleasingly **memorable** for someone.

So, no, that idiom doesn't mean "put me out of my misery" in any scenario.
@Xanne has already explained the scene in Dirty Harry.

As pointed by @Justin, how can a day be **memorable** if you're dead?

Comment: Thank you. Clearly explained.

Comment: "How can a day be memorable if you're dead?" - ever heard of sarcasm?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, I have. And I was thinking also in cockroaches with suicidal tendencies but I still think that it does not quite fit that context.